# 110V AC/ 9V AC power adapter (America) Vs. 220V AC/ 9V AC power adapter (Europe)

Tags: power, voltage, adapter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)

I have a device that I brought to Europe from America. It has a 110V AC/ 9V AC power adapter that stopped working. Over here I found a 220V AC/ 9V. I'd like to know if it'll work despite the 110V/220V difference since the device will receive the same 9V

Comment: You'll have to look at the current needs but assuming both are 9v DC yes.

Comment: both adapters are 9VAC.

Comment: It doesn't matter how the power supply makes 9V, only that it does.  The current rating also has to meet the minimum requirement.  For more detail, see the question I linked to above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 9 V AC will be 9 V AC; the secondary side doesn't know about the primary voltage. So that's no problem.

What could be important is that in Europe you'll have 50 Hz output, whereas the US adapter will output 60 Hz. (Well, it doesn't *make* 60 Hz, that's what the mains supplies in the US.) This is not a problem if the device converts it to DC (most likely), but if you would use it for a digital clock that will run 17 % slow if it gets its clock from the mains frequency, and expects 60 Hz.